# node app.js doesn't show anything in the browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, typeerror

hello guyz i am playing with NodeJS and expressJS actually i was looking the tutorial and writing the same code in my editor but in the video he is getting the result perfectly but on my machine it doen't work when i run command in the browser http://localhost:3000/ it's not working can anyone help me where the problem is?
thank you in advance.

```
    var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// handle file uploads
app.use(multer({dest: './uploads'}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// handle express sessions
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave:true
}));

//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//validator
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(pram, msg, value){
    var namespace = pram.split('.')
, root = namespace.shift()
, formPram = root;

while(namespace.length){
formPram += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
}
return {
    pram: formPram,
    msg : msg,
    value : value
};
}
}));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `app.listen(3000)`, or is your project generated with the `express` cli? Which video are you talking about by the way? Do you have any error log in your terminal?

Comment: yes i am having too many errors in my terminal

Comment: Can you share with us the errors you get?

Comment: i have in /bin/www

Comment: Error: Cannot find module './Routes.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asad_\OneDrive\My_Work\my_Projects\NodeJs\nodeauth\routes\users.js:10:18)